# ZXingWidgetController does not Scan QR after built for App Store Provisioning

Tags: ios, xcode, zxing

So I had built my app and had successfully been approved in the app store, but the problem is the ZXing scanner does not scan QR anymore..

I did try also built my app as Ad Hoc and Development Provisioning, and it works just fine...

But, when build for App Store, after approve, it just wont work anymore (really does not scan no matter how clear the QR Code is)..

Are there any Build Settings to change or any Housekeeping before Archiving for App Store?
If there are stuffs i missed please do tell, thanks :)

Comment: I don't remember having to set Skip Install to YES for ZXing project (also included in my app) - but app is live in App Store and QR scanning part happily does its job.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information here.

As mentioned in the [ZXing FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), if you happen to be using an older version of Xcode (before 4.2), if you compile with any version of llvm (llvm-gcc or clang) and turn on optimizations, ZXing will fail because of compiler errors.

If that's not it, you'll have to start tracking down the Xcode settings. The Archive action should be using the Release build configuration and if you set the Run action to use that configuration (select the project portion of the scheme pull down, then Edit Scheme ...), you should be able to replicate the failure.